# Pickadate Time Selector Disappears on Click on JQuery UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, pickadate

If you open a time picker in a jQuery dialog using the classic theme and try to use the time picker scroll bar to move down the time list, the time list disappears.

You can see the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/7c2z840a/7/

```
jQuery("#tmStart").pickatime({
    editable: true,
    format: 'h:i A',
    formatSubmit: 'HH:i',
    //hiddenSuffix: '_FORMATTED',
    interval: 15,
    min: [7,0],
    max: [21,0]
});
```

The problem appears in both Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE.

Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: You're going to need to override the height of the list of times so that it is what is scrolling instead of the container that is scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following line:

```
    jQuery("#tmStart_root").find(".picker__box").css({height: "100px", overflow: "auto"});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cu0y9hyn/1/

Comment: Works great. Much easier to implement in my situation too than the other proposed solution of only creating the timepicker after creating the dialog instance.

Answer (score 0):

The appearing scrollbar belongs to dialog widget rather than datepicker. Clicking on the scrollbar has the same effect as clicking elsewhere which results in closing datepicker

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create the pickatime instance after you create the dialog instance

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem with datetimepicker and numberOfMonths: 12

I changed this: `<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>`

to this: `<div id="datepicker"> </div>`

changes dialog to inline

now scrolling does not close datetimepicker.